# check if there are message incoming from clients in a Java server

Tags: java, sockets

I have a chat Java Server, actually it receive the client and insert his id into a deque and his id and socket into an hashmap. In an another thread the server iterate the deque and check if clients are sending message, in case the server manage it with some operatorion in a other thread. My "Problem" is that iterate the deque (or a list) is a slow operation, if i had milions of people connected it should iterate too many item. so i'm asking you if there's one better method to do this. here's the code of the bottle neck:

```
while(true){ 
    String id = MainServer.deque_id.poll();
    Socket socket = MainServer.map_socket.get(id);
    if(new PushbackInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).available() > 0) 
        MainServer.queue_manage_message.put(new ManageMessageTask(id, socket, true)); 
    MainServer.deque_id.addLast(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need need to construct a PushbackInputStream just to call available() and then throw the stream away. All InputStreams have available(), although it doesn't work in all of them.

With blocking I/O you need at least one thread per connection, maybe two, one for input and one for output.

Or else you need to look into non-blocking and multiplexed I/O using Selectors and Channels. See the java.nio.channels package.

Comment: i've tried to call available() from inputStream class and it doesn't work (the solution was to use PushbackInputStream). i'll study the NIO. thank you

Comment: PushbackInputStream.available() can't possibly work any better than the available() method of the stream it wraps, unless  you have pushed something back into it, which you haven't.

Comment: @AnimalsPf: Your usage of the PIS is according to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PushbackInputStream.java#PushbackInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.InputStream%2Cint%29) a no-op.